# Doctrine: bidirectional OneToOne relationship, both entities being deleted

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hey guys so I have 2 entities with a bidirectional OneToOne relationship:

**Sale.php**

```
/**
 * @var TransportInvoice
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WKDA\Common\Entity\Car\TransportInvoice\TransportInvoice",  mappedBy="sale")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="transport_invoice", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $transportInvoice;
```

**TransportInvoice.php**

```
/**
 * @var Sale
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WKDA\Common\Entity\Car\Sale", inversedBy="transportInvoice", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sale", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $sale;
```

In my controller, to delete a transport invoice from the sale, the following is done:

```
$transportInvoice = $car->getSale()->getTransportInvoice();
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();

            $em->remove($transportInvoice);
            $em->flush();
```

This deletes the TransportInvoice, but it deletes the Sale object as well. I don't want the Sale object to be deleted, I just want the TransportInvoice parameter within sale to be null. What am I not understanding?

If this is not clear let me know, thanks for your help!

Comment: It could also be the orphanRemoval.

Comment: Tried removing orphanRemoval, no luck

Comment: Check who deletes the entity. Is it a cascade delete in the database or in Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the relation design. In your example Sale is the main entity, so the transport_invoice reference is not needed. The "sale" reference in TransportInvoice.php is all that doctrine need, so edit Sale as follow an try again.

```
/**
 * @var TransportInvoice
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="WKDA\Common\Entity\Car\TransportInvoice\TransportInvoice",  mappedBy="sale")
 */
protected $transportInvoice;
```

I hope it help you.